# Magento EE 1.11.1, Full Page Cache issue with mobile theme?

Tags: magento, caching

I've went through many forums, but I was unable to solve the FPC problem in Magento EE 1.11 version. When I browsing the mobile theme it is taking web theme instead, because of FPC. If I disable the FPC, the performance will go down.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Since Magento EE is a commercial product including support: have you already contacted the [Magento EE Support](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/ee/)?

Answer (score 2):

The theme is not used as part of the FPC uri and therefore there is only one cache per package.

I wrote a little extension to fix the issue and you can grab it on Github.

https://github.com/benjy14/MobileFpcFix

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that the design exceptions support in Enterprise/PageCache work at the *package* level and not the *theme* level. Take a look at the code referencing design exceptions in app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php. My first suggestion would be to contact EE support, perhaps they can provide an appropriate solution or a patch. Alternatively, you can modify the caching key mechanism by rewriting enterprise_pagecache/processor:

```
public function prepareCacheId($id)
{
    $package         = Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName();
    $templateTheme   = Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template');
    $id              = $id.'_'.$package.'_'.$templateTheme;
    return parent::prepareCacheId($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that does not require any patching of code:

Add an exception with the same regex-expression as you have in the themes-section into the package section and link it to the exact same package name as the "Current Package Name" is set to.

**Prereqs:**
Only one exception per section on the theme levels, e.g., `iPhone|iPad -> iphone`
(and not `iPhone -> iphone` + `iPad -> iphone`)

**Explanation why it works:**
The enterprise page-caching is taking the package exceptions into account when generating the cacheid.
It does however not check if the package names are identical!
So even if the exception package is identical as the main, a different cacheid will be generated, and since the regex exceptions in the themes section are identical, they will be stored in the full page cache using the new chacheid.

**Example:**
In the "enterprise" package, there are 2 themes "default" and "iphone".
You wish to run the theme "iphone" by adding the exception `iPhone|iPad` 
for the "Templates", "Skin" and "Layout" in the "Themes" subsection.

In the "Package" subsection:
Set "Current Package Name" to "enterprise".
Add an exception to the package with `iPhone|iPad` -> "enterprise"

In the "Themes" subsection:
Add an exception to the "Templates" with `iPhone|iPad -> enterprise`
Add an exception to the "Skin" with `iPhone|iPad -> enterprise`
Add an exception to the "Layout" with `iPhone|iPad -> enterprise`
Set "Default" to "default"

**Note:**
Do not forget to clear the FPC in System->Cache Management before testing it.